# ¿Cómo puedo transferir tokens ERC20 usando la biblioteca php sc0Vu/web3.php?

Tags: php, laravel, tokens, transacciones

Me gustaría que alguien me instruyera sobre cómo usar la biblioteca [sc0Vu/web3.php](https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php) Estoy interesado en algún ejemplo de implementación yo mismo firmando las transacciones local mente, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: La misma biblioteca ofrece ejemplos https://github.com/web3p/web3.php/tree/master/examples .

Comment: esos ejemplos me sirven si voy a usar un nodo local pero si quiero usar un nodo remoto y firmar mis propias transacciones en local no me sirven